# Skype only logs in as root

Tags: 12.04, skype, sudo, root

I just installed Skype on my Ubuntu 12.04 again and somehow I can only login if I start Skype via root (sudo skype) in the terminal. If I try otherwise via dash or just "skype" without sudo permission I can't log in, it says "Login failed" or "Sign in failed" (got the German version).

Comment: Please go in more details! Is there any error message, the login process is too long, or times out?!... E.g. try with other Skype account. Otherwise, Skype version?

Comment: Tip: Don't use `sudo`with GUI programs.

Comment: If it is required, I suggest `gksudo <pogram>` from `Alt`+`F2`.

Comment: Strange, I just noticed that my post is kinda cut, sorry.
After I enter the login details and hit it, it takes about 3-5 seconds then it says that it couldn't log in, I think in English it's "Login failed" or similar. Also newest Skype version 4.0 (at least it should be the newest since I updated all packages etc.).

Comment: Did you installed the Skype package from the Skype website? or from the repositories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the following command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: ~/.Skype
```

The command will give back ownership on all of Skype's config files to your own user, as you've probably ran Skype with `sudo` once. Which, after that, root took ownership of some of the files in its config and history files.

If you don't need your Skype logs, you can also remove the `~/.Skype` directory (renaming would be safer).

```
mv ~/.Skype ~/.Skype.bak
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked just fine.
I also thought about the permissions but I couldn't think of a reason why only root should have access.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command it's Working for you: `curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nu11secur1ty/Kali-Linux-skype/master/fix.sh | bash`

Comment: Users should always be aware that running bash scripts from unknown sources is a serious security risk. So execute at your own risk.

Comment: @zx485 you are right. always read the full script before executing it. I try this and it's working fine for me.